# Using Async Pipe Instead of Subscribing, While Getting The Data From Service

Tags: angular, async-pipe

this is my first time posting here, and I'm new to Angular. I've tried looking for solutions to my problem, but haven't been able to find one that helps my problem. So I have an agent detail component that uses a service to make a getAgent() request. And instead of subscribing to this call in the component, I want to use the async pipe technique to display the data onto the agent detail template. Below is my old working solution, and after that is my attempted solution on trying to make an async call. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or am I doing something completely wrong? Is it even possible to use async pipe in my situation? If anymore information is needed please let me know, and thank you so much in advance for the help and advice!

Here is the service:
[agent service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxuVo.png)

Here is the working component & template: [component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa22F.png) [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muK2o.png)

And lastly here is what I've been trying to work on trying to get async pipe to work: [component async](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrkQZ.png) [template async](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRUQt.png)

The error I keep getting: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5jci.png)

Comment: Do you want agents or one single agent? Because currently you are trying to set getAgent which return Observable<AgentInterface> to Observable<AgentInterface[]>

Comment: @IdontwearString Yes I am trying to get a single agent. I guess for a little more context, there is an agent list, and when I click on a specific agent it navigates to the agent detail component. Thanks so much!

Comment: Also when I try to call the getAgent() method from service, it requires a parameter and typescript gets mad at me..

Comment: Get an array of agents to your agents$ observable instead. Consume agents$ in the template with async pipe, loop thru every agent and assign it to agent detail component thru input. It would be nice if you could make a stackblitz reproducing the issue, that way its easier to help out.

Comment: Maybe this will help you understand: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hbwv7e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @IdontwearString thank you so much for the reply. I'm sorry I don't know how to use stackblitz. Would you be able to hop on a discord call or any platform and I can share my screen to show you my code? I'd appreciate it so much. I'm still not understanding your solution and not sure if it can apply to my case. Thank you so much

Comment: @IdontwearString also idk if this helps, but i'm routing to a view with parameters to get specific agent's name, and then showing the name based on parameter.